github/act workflow build cython project and push to pypi
I've got a really simple cython/python project. After blocking on this for a year and a month, I'm finally ready to beg for help. I'm trying to use the simplest / most standard setup possible, so I've just got a setup.py with a few lines of code. Locally, I use pip install . and it "just works." But trying to use this in any sort of downstream capacity is absolutely non-trivial. I've been shipping several thousand-line, unmaintainable monoliths because of it. I really need to push these packages somewhere (like PyPi) so they can be re-used in a reasonable way (i.e., pip install <pkgname>).

And what have you tried so far? What problems do you have with it? How does your setup.py or workflow look like?
